# Xamarin Forms: How to clear the read push notification using the notification id

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, push-notification

I have implemented push notifications for my chat application using FCM. My application has groups same like WhatsApp groups. New notifications will receive when chatting inside a group. **I need to clear the notifications which are already read.**

I found a [blog](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-programmatically-clearcancel-notifications-in-xamarin-forms/) for this feature. But it is not working for me. My codes are added below:

**In PCL:**

```
public interface IPushCancel
    {
        void CancelPush(long id);
    }
```

**In Android:**

```
public class PushCancelService : IPushCancel
    {
        public void CancelPush(long id)
        {
            var intent = CreateIntent(id);
            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Android.App.Application.Context, (int)id, intent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);
            var alarmManager = GetAlarmManager();
            alarmManager.Cancel(pendingIntent);
            var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(Android.App.Application.Context);
            notificationManager.CancelAll();

        }
        private AlarmManager GetAlarmManager()
        {
            var alarmManager = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService) as AlarmManager;
            return alarmManager;
        }

        private Intent CreateIntent(long id)
        {
            return new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity /*"Here we have to put GCM Listener class"*/))
              .SetAction("LocalNotifierIntent" + id);
        }
    }
```

**In IOS:**

```
public class PushCancelService : IPushCancel
    {
        private const string NotificationKey = "LocalNotificationKey";
        public void CancelPush(long id)
        {
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.CancelAllLocalNotifications();
            var notifications = UIApplication.SharedApplication.ScheduledLocalNotifications;
            var notification = notifications.Where(n => n.UserInfo.ContainsKey(NSObject.FromObject(NotificationKey))).FirstOrDefault(n => n.UserInfo[NotificationKey].Equals(NSObject.FromObject(id)));
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.CancelAllLocalNotifications();
            if (notification != null)
            {
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.CancelLocalNotification(notification);
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.CancelAllLocalNotifications();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Notification ID**

In `MainActivity` I am passing the `notification_id` like below:

```
public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {
        base.OnMessageReceived(message);
        var myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<webContentList>>(webContentList);
        string webcontentId = myData[0].webContentDefinitionId.ToString();
        try
        {
            //passing groupid and notification id with a blank space
            MessagingCenter.Send<object, string>(this, "webcontentId", webcontentId + " " + message.MessageId);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("exception:>>" + exc);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error:>>" + ex);
    }
}
```

In `IOS` I am passing the `notification_id` like below from `AppDelegate.cs`:

```
public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
        {
            var myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<webContentList>>(userInfo[new NSString("webContentList")] as NSString);
            string notificationId = (userInfo[new NSString("gcm.message_id")] as NSString).ToString();

            if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationState.Equals(UIApplicationState.Active))
            {
                //App is in foreground. Act on it.
                if (myData != null)
                {
                    string webcontentId = myData[0].webContentDefinitionId.ToString();
                    try
                    {
                        //Passing notification id and group id from here through MessagingCenter
                        MessagingCenter.Send<object, string>(this, "webcontentId", webcontentId + " " + notificationId);
                    }
                    catch (Exception exc)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("messagecenterexception:>>" + exc);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessagingCenter.Send<object, List<webContentList>>(this, "messagedata", myData);
            }
        }
```

Finally, I am calling the notification clear `DependencyService` from my group page like below:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, string>(this, "webcontentId", (object obj, string notifWebcontentId) => {
                if (notifWebcontentId != "")
                {
                    string[] multiArray = notifWebcontentId.Split(' ');
                    //Checking foreground group id and notification group id are same
                    if (multiArray[0] == webcontentId)
                    {
                        DependencyService.Get<IPushCancel>().CancelPush(long.Parse(multiArray[1]));
                        RefreshMessageList();
                    }
                }
            });
```

**Observations**

**IOS**

No error or exception is showing in ios, but code execution is not going inside of the following `if.

```
if (notification != null)
            {
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.CancelLocalNotification(notification);
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.CancelAllLocalNotifications();
            }
```

**Android**

Getting `TargetInvocationException` when sending notification id from Mainactitivity.

**Exception Details:**

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

**Please help me to solve implement this feature. I need to clear the read message notifications automatically. Otherwise, the user will struggle by a lot of notifications.**

Comment: For iOS ,`CancelLocalNotification` is used to remove local notificaiton before and deprecated after iOS 10 ,use `RemoveDeliveredNotifications` instead.

Comment: And why would you want clear the notification when receive it? This will cause you could not get the content of the notification.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT My application is a chat application having groups same like WhatsApp. When posting a message in a group, it will receive notification for all the other members. When tapping that notification the corresponding group will open and show all the messages. So now my app is open and have the same group on the UI. If a new message will send by someone else now, I will get a new notification. Also, the message list gets refreshed since I have the same group is in the foreground mode.

Comment: In this case, the message is already get refreshed, so I don't want to show the notification for the user. The same feature like WhatsApp.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Can you have a look on this thread?https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/162537/xamarin-forms-how-to-clear-the-read-push-notification-using-the-notification-id/p1?new=1